Draw Tubular surfaces
I would like to find out a way to draw a tubular surface around a helix in LaTex without using the 3d-tikz. I'm seeking for a picture only made by tikzpicture. Also, I'm finding how I may draw in tikz a regular curve (not a circle) and a tube around it. Anyone could help me?
For example, I made this tube around a circle, but I want to generalized for a smooth closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is enough with an example.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.6]

\fill[cyan!30] (0,0) circle (5cm);
\draw[black, line width=1pt] (0,0) circle (5cm);



\draw[black, line width=3pt] (0,0) circle (3cm);


\fill[white] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[black, line width=1pt] (0,0) circle (1cm);


\node at (3.5, 0) {$\mathbb{S}^1$};

\draw[<->, dashed, line width=1.5pt] (0,5) -- (0,3);
\draw[<->, dashed, line width=1.5pt] (0,1) -- (0,3);
\node at (0.5, 4) {$t$};
\node at (0.5, 2) {$t$};
\end{tikzpicture}


In addition to accomplishing this in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728413/319072, I thought I'd post an asymptote solution.
Asymptote is better because it handles the 3D layering automatically, and lets you use Splines. I should mention that while I wrote most of the code myself, I was corrected on a formula by ChatGPT.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
    import graph3;
    unitsize(1cm);
    currentprojection =
        orthographic(0,2,1);

    // Function to generate a point on the unit sphere
    triple sphere(real azimuth, real polar) {
        return (
            cos(polar) * cos(azimuth),
            cos(polar) * sin(azimuth),
            sin(polar)
        );
    }

    // Helix function
    triple helix(real t) {
        return (
            2 * cos(t),  // x-coordinate
            2 * sin(t),  // y-coordinate
            t           // z-coordinate
        );
    }

    // Define the helix path
    path3 thehelix = graph(helix, 0, 4*pi);
    draw(thehelix);

    // Helicoid function
    triple helicoid(pair uv) {
        real t = uv.x;
        real theta = uv.y;
        return (
            helix(t).x + sphere(t,theta).x,
            helix(t).y + sphere(t,theta).y,
            helix(t).z + sphere(t,theta).z
        );
    }

    // Create the surface of the helicoid
    surface thehelicoid = surface(helicoid, (0, -3pi/2), (4*pi, 0pi), Spline);
    draw(thehelicoid, surfacepen=material(white, emissivepen=0.2 white));
\end{asy}
\end{document}



Concerning the linked post, I did improve it a bit aesthetically. That being said, the code could benefit from better readability. I will append what I have to the answer now, and maybe correct it later if I have time. Basically, You run a python script which both calculates the math for you, and writes the .tex file for you based on those calculations.
import math
import subprocess
import numpy as np

def signed_distance(point, plane_point, normal_vector):
    return np.dot(point - plane_point, normal_vector) / np.linalg.norm(normal_vector)

def sort_shapes(shapes, plane_point, normal_vector):
    distances = []
    for shape in shapes:
        if shape['type'] == 'rectangle':
            # Average the coordinates of the rectangle vertices
            center = np.mean(shape['vertices'], axis=0)
        elif shape['type'] == 'line':
            # Average the coordinates of the line endpoints
            center = np.mean(shape['endpoints'], axis=0)
        distance = signed_distance(center, plane_point, normal_vector)
        distances.append((distance, shape))
    return [shape for _, shape in sorted(distances)]

def sphereX(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.cos(math.radians(polar)) * math.cos(math.radians(azimuthal))

def sphereY(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.cos(math.radians(polar)) * math.sin(math.radians(azimuthal))

def sphereZ(polar: float, azimuthal: float) -> float:
    return math.sin(math.radians(polar))

viewdirX = sphereX(90 - 60, -30)
viewdirY = sphereY(90 - 60, -30)
viewdirZ = sphereZ(90 - 60, -30)

the_normal_vector = np.array([viewdirX, viewdirY, viewdirZ])

shapes = []

for Vt in range(10, 720 + 1, 10):
    current_lastx = sphereX(90, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    current_lasty = sphereY(90, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    current_lastz = sphereZ(90, Vt - 10) + 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

    line_lastx = 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    line_lasty = 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
    line_lastz = 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

    for Vtt in range(90, 350 + 1, 10):
        Vxo = sphereX(Vtt, Vt) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        Vyo = sphereY(Vtt, Vt) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        Vzo = sphereZ(Vtt, Vt) + 5 * Vt / 360

        Vxt = sphereX(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        Vyt = sphereY(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        Vzt = sphereZ(Vtt + 10, Vt) + 5 * Vt / 360

        Vxth = sphereX(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt - 10))
        Vyth = sphereY(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt - 10))
        Vzth = sphereZ(Vtt + 10, Vt - 10) + 5 * (Vt - 10) / 360

        line_nextx = 4 * math.cos(math.radians(Vt))
        line_nexty = 4 * math.sin(math.radians(Vt))
        line_nextz = 5 * Vt / 360

        # Add rectangle to shapes
        shapes.append({
            'type': 'rectangle',
            'vertices': [
                (current_lastx, current_lasty, current_lastz),
                (Vxo, Vyo, Vzo),
                (Vxt, Vyt, Vzt),
                (Vxth, Vyth, Vzth)
            ]
        })

        # Add line to shapes
        shapes.append({
            'type': 'line',
            'endpoints': [
                (line_lastx, line_lasty, line_lastz),
                (line_nextx, line_nexty, line_nextz)
            ]
        })

        current_lastx = Vxth
        current_lasty = Vyth
        current_lastz = Vzth

        line_lastx = line_nextx
        line_lasty = line_nexty
        line_lastz = line_nextz

# Sort shapes based on their depth
plane_point = np.array([0, 0, 0])  # Define a plane point (can be adjusted)
sorted_shapes = sort_shapes(shapes, plane_point, the_normal_vector)

# Write to TeX file
with open("TeX_file.tex", "w") as TeX:
    start = r"""
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
"""
    end = r"""
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
"""
    TeX.write(start)
    for shape in sorted_shapes:
        if shape['type'] == 'rectangle':
            rect = shape['vertices']
            command = f"""
            \\fill[white] ({rect[0][0]},{rect[0][1]},{rect[0][2]}) -- ({rect[1][0]},{rect[1][1]},{rect[1][2]}) -- ({rect[2][0]},{rect[2][1]},{rect[2][2]}) -- ({rect[3][0]},{rect[3][1]},{rect[3][2]}) -- cycle;
            \\fill[opacity=0.5] ({rect[0][0]},{rect[0][1]},{rect[0][2]}) -- ({rect[1][0]},{rect[1][1]},{rect[1][2]}) -- ({rect[2][0]},{rect[2][1]},{rect[2][2]}) -- ({rect[3][0]},{rect[3][1]},{rect[3][2]}) -- cycle;
            \\draw ({rect[0][0]},{rect[0][1]},{rect[0][2]}) -- ({rect[1][0]},{rect[1][1]},{rect[1][2]}) -- ({rect[2][0]},{rect[2][1]},{rect[2][2]}) -- ({rect[3][0]},{rect[3][1]},{rect[3][2]}) -- cycle;
            """
            TeX.write(command)
        elif shape['type'] == 'line':
            line = shape['endpoints']
            command = f"""
            \\draw[thick,red] ({line[0][0]},{line[0][1]},{line[0][2]}) -- ({line[1][0]},{line[1][1]},{line[1][2]});
            """
            TeX.write(command)
    TeX.write(end)

subprocess.run(['lualatex', "TeX_file.tex"])



Maybe you could post another answer with your tikz-3dplot code (this one is very nice, by he way).

@jlab Thank you, I needed to learn asymptote because tikz struggles with 3D - had no idea how much simpler it was! I added a revised version of that code to this post.
